# « Rue ... » ou « rue de ... », lequel choisir ?

Tags: vocabulaire, prépositions, noms

Dans mon livre de français, il y a une « rue de Ménilmontant », mais aussi une « rue Dénoyez ». Je pense que, quand le nom de la rue est quasiment un nom commun, on utilise la préposition « de » comme « rue du Pressoir ». Mais les deux noms ci-dessus sont plutôt des noms propres. Donc, quand est-ce qu'on utilise « rue » ou « rue de » ? Est-ce qu'il y a une règle ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- On utilise « Rue nom propre » lorsqu'il s'agit d'un nom de personne.
- On utilise « Rue *de* » dans les autres cas.

**Exceptions:** (Crédit @jlliagre)

- Nom de personne précédé d'un titre *Rue du Général de Gaulle*
- Le nom de la rue est (ou commence par) un adjectif :

  - Rue Longue-des-Capucins
  - Rue Blanche

Comment: 1. Sauf si le nom de personne est précédé d'un titre *Rue du Général de Gaulle*. 2. Sauf s'il s'agit d'un adjectif: [Rue Longue-des-Capucins](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rue_Longue-des-Capucins), [Rue Blanche](http://www.v2asp.paris.fr/commun/v2asp/v2/nomenclature_voies/Voieactu/1019.nom.htm)

Comment: @jlliagre: tout à fait, merci.